# How to stop child QTabWidget to inherit style sheet from parent QTabWidget

Tags: c++, qt, qt4.7

I have done below styling on `QTabWidget` (which has a `QTabWidget` inside one of it's tab):

```
QTabBar::tab {
    border: 2px solid grey;
}
QTabBar::tab:selected {
    border-color: red;
}
```

After this the tab widget looks like:

[image]

I do not want child `QTabWidget` to inherit style from parent. I know one way to achieve this is by using object name in style sheet but I don't have the object name of `QTabBar` associated with `QTabWidget`. Please let me know how I can achieve the desired behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use object name on the QTabWidget:

```
parent_tab_widget->setObjectName("parent_tab_widget");
```

In style sheet:

```
#parent_tab_widget > QTabBar::tab {
    border: 2px solid grey;
}
#parent_tab_widget > QTabBar::tab:selected {
    border-color: red;
}
```

More info on style sheet selectors in Qt4 [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/stylesheet-syntax.html#selector-types). The answer is a combination of the ID selector with the child selector.

Comment: Thank you very much, this worked. If possible could you provide me a reference for this parent object name concept.

Comment: @Sajal I edited my answer with a link to Qt's documentation on selectors